# Sign conundrum while deriving electrostatic potential

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential-energy, conventions, differentiation

[image]

Consider a fixed, positive Point charge $q1$, kept at the origin. Another (positive) charge, $q2$, is being brought from $\infty$ to the point $(r,0)$, by an external agent *slowly*. We wish to calculate the work done by the external agent (and thus derive the "potential" of the point charge $q1$, being defined as $w_{ext}/q2$ (or as $-w_{electric}/q2$)). Suppose we consider a position $(x,0)$:

- The magnitude of force is going to be $kq1q2/x^2$. We will thus have, $\vec{F}=\dfrac{-kq1q2}{x^2}\hat{i}$.
- When we displace it from a position $(x,0)$ to $(x-dx,0)$, the displacement vector$(\vec{ds})$ will be $(x-dx)\hat{i}-x\hat(i)=-dx\hat{i}$.
- Using $dw$=$\vec{F}.\vec{ds}$, we will get $dw=\dfrac{kq1q2}{x^2}dx$. Upon integrating from $\infty$ (initial position) to $r$ (final position), we get :
  $$w_{ext}=-\dfrac{kq1q2}{r}$$ and thus
  $$V(r)= w_{ext}/q2 =-\dfrac{kq1}{r}$$
  which is completely absurd. I tried to be as rigorous as possible with the definitions, vectors etc and yet a -ve sign has crept in somewhere.

The only issue seems to be with the treatment of $dx$. Although , I took $dx$ to be the *magnitude* of displacement, and accounted for the direction by using $-\hat{i}$.A possible argument seems to be "$x$ decreases, so $dx$ is a negative quantity. So the "magnitude" should be $-dx$. My two concerns:

- What is then, the issue with displacement=$\vec{r_{final}} - \vec{r_{initial}}$ that simply yields $-dx\hat{i}$?
- Simply "putting" a - sign before $dx$ after claiming "$dx$ is negative" seems to be arbitrary. There should be an argument (like I presented in the previous bullet point) that will produce the - sign for the magnitude, and thus making the vector $(-dx)(-\hat{i})$.

The main essence of this problem seems to be *rigorously* defining what $dx$ actually represents, for a quantity $x$.

I believe the entire thing can be summarized by one question:

**What is wrong in writing displacement=$\vec{r_{final}} - \vec{r_{initial}}$ that simply yields $-dx\hat{i}$? If I had $(x+dx)$ instead of $(x-dx)$,then the derivation would be correct. But why is this the Case?**

Comment: Isn't potential energy-ve of work done?

Comment: -ve of work done by (electrostatic forces). +ve of work done by the external agent.

Comment: What exactly do you call absurd in this problem?

Comment: A positive charge having a -ve potential.

Comment: What is the F in the first bullet? Is it the force between the the two charges? Why there is a – sign in the formula?

Comment: Yes, I cant think of F being anything else other than that. As to "why is there a negative sign in the formula", that is **precisely what my question is**.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law F=kqQ/r² . There is no minus. Electric charges of the same sign repel each other.

Comment: the - in the F expression corresponds to the vector (-i).

Comment: I don't see the coordinate system, or _i_ versor in the drawing. I assume it's pointing right. The repulsive electrostatic force on q2 should be pointing right as well. Hence there shouldn't be a minus in the formula describing electrostatic force acting on q2.

Comment: This question is the source of a lot of confusion.  The main source is figuring out how to do an integral when you are moving right to left instead of left to right. That problem can be solved if instead you go from left to right.  [Here's how it's done](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/547418/5739).  The context there is gravity, but it's essentially the same problem.

Comment: @user1079505 If you read the entire question carefully, you will find that its obvious that F in the vector form in my question, is the force exerted by the *external agent*. Which is equal in magnitude to the force exerted by the fixed charge on q2, and **opposite** in direction, since we are making q2 move **slowly**. Yes, indeed q2 is repelled. And unfortunately, you are completely skipping the essence of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there is a confusion in the use and/or interpretation of $d\vec s$

- as an infinitesimal element of a directed path

and

- as a specific displacement in the problem.

You want to write
$$
\begin{align}
W_{ext}
&=\int_P^Q \vec F_{ext}\cdot d\vec s\\
&=\int_{x_P}^{x_Q} (F_{ext,x}\ \hat\imath)\cdot (dx\ \hat\imath)\\
&=\int_{x_P}^{x_Q} F_{ext,x}\ dx\\
\end{align}
$$
by expressing the symbolic-integrand in coordinates, say, your x-coordinate running to the right.
The element of path $d\vec s$ (which is not the specific displacement of your problem) is being expressed in terms of the x-coordinate.
I have not made any statement about $P$ or $Q$.
The specific values of $P$ and $Q$ do not determine how
the element of path is expressed in terms of the x-coordinate.

For simplicity, if $F_{ext,x}$ were constant, then this evaluates to
$$\begin{align}
W_{ext} = F_{ext,x} (x_Q-x_P)
\end{align}$$
This work-by-the-external-force is positive when

- $F_{ext,x}>0$ and $(x_Q-x_P)>0$ 
  (the force pushes to the right, and the particle is displaced to the right... so $x_Q > x_P$),

or when

- $F_{ext,x}<0$ and $(x_Q-x_P)<0$ 
  (the force pushes to the left, and the particle is displaced to the left... so $x_Q < x_P$)

In your specific problem essentially maintaining equilibrium of $q_2$ during transport,
$$\vec F_{ext\ \rm [on\ q_2]} \stackrel{Newton\\ 2^{nd}\ Law}{=} -\vec F_{elec,\ \rm on\  q_2} = -\left(\frac{ k q_1 q_2}{x^2} \hat\imath \right),$$
you have
$$
\begin{align}
W_{ext}
&=\int_P^Q F_{ext,x}\ dx\\
&=\int_{x_P}^{x_Q} \left(-\frac{k q_1 q_2}{x^2}\right) \ dx\\
&=kq_1q_2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right|_{x_P}^{x_Q}\\
&=kq_1q_2\left(\frac{1}{x_Q}-\frac{1}{x_P}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Now is the time to specify your initial and final values, $x_P$ and $x_Q$.
With $x_P=\infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
W_{ext}
&=kq_1q_2\frac{1}{x_Q}>0
\end{align}
$$

(for a related answer, see
[Positive work along path](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/440259/positive-work-along-path)

and
https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/dot-product-in-the-gravitational-potential-energy-formula.815230/
)

Comment: How did you write the displacement vector $ds$=$dx\hat{i}$? This is essentially what the question boils down to

Comment: and more importantly, whats incorrect with Writing displacement as : $\vec{r_{final}} - \vec{r_{initial}}$ that simply yields $-dx\hat{i}$?

Comment: From my answer, "The element of path $d\vec s$" .. "is not the specific displacement of your problem [call that $\Delta \vec d$ to distinguish them]". While working on the integrand alone, I hold off any consideration of the limits P and Q. I just ask how can a piece of the path $d\vec s$ be described in terms of x.. the answer is $d\vec s=dx\hat\imath$. Thinking in the way I described seems to lead to consistent and correct expressions (without having to fudge a sign in the end). I can't explicitly pin down what is incorrect in your next comment... other than it seems to go wrong.

Comment: As you ask others not to skip the essence of the question, please do not skip the details of my answer. Go through it and see if it makes sense, with variations of your choice of P and Q, etc... Then, ask what your proposed variation with your second comment implies... it likely double-counts the orientation.